# Generate MBTiles from WMTS with GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate, wmts, mbtiles

I have a WMTS source and I would like to generate a MBTiles file from this url (I have access rights on this source). I would need to:

- Download the WMTS
- Clip it according to a vector layer (polygon)
- Generate tiles between a min and max zoom level (MBTiles)

Is it possible to perform these operations using GDAL in python (and especially `gdal_translate`)?
I have seen that which seems interesting: https://github.com/MerginMaps/docs/issues/140 but I do not understand how to apply it concretely.

Comment: Note that in the MerginMaps example the first step is download the WMTS or WMS XML, that is the GetCapabilities response, rather than any tiles/images

Comment: It is possible by using the WMTS driver for reading the source data https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wmts.html